# Printing out the properties of an object

Tags: javascript

I'm following Code Academy's Javascript tutorial. Here's the lesson, I'm having trouble with:

> Use a for-in loop to print out all the properties of nyc.

Here's my code:

```
var nyc = {
    fullName: "New York City",
    mayor: "Bill de Blasio",
    population: 8000000,
    boroughs: 5
};

for(var x in nyc) {
    console.log(nyc[x]);
}
```

When I execute this, Code Academy gives me the following error:

> Oops, try again. It looks like you didn't print nyc's fullName

I used Chrome's developer tools to run this code and I seem to be getting the appropriate output:

```
New York City
Bill de Blasio
8000000
5
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit: I took Pointy's advice on changing the inside of the for-in loop to console.log(x). I still got the same error until I closed the Code Academy tab and opened up a new one.**

Comment: Your code most certainly will not do that.  The values of "x" will be "fullName", "mayor", "population", "boroughs".

Comment: @Pointy pasted the wrong code. Just fixed it

Comment: You'll have to link to the relevant CodeAcademy exercise, but most likely it's just an issue of the question being unclear and/or their code that checks answers being finicky or broken.

Comment: Here you go: http://www.codecademy.com/courses/objects-ii/1/4?curriculum_id=506324b3a7dffd00020bf661

Comment: Question 9 wants just the property **names** (`console.log(x)`). The next question, 10, wants the property **values** (`console.log(nyc[x])`).

Comment: Yeah tried that. It's giving me the same error. I think the problem has something to do with Chrome because CA accepts the console.log(x) code in incognito mode

Answer (score 2):

`x` is your key to get the value you use the key to access it inside the object `nyc` as in

```
for(var x in nyc) {
    console.log(nyc[x]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var x in nyc) {
    // x refers to the current property name.
    console.log(x);
    // To look up the *value* of that property, use the [] notation
    console.log(nyc[x]);
}
```